# Splitting of a string using Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, c#-4.0

I have string of the following format:

```
string test = "test.BO.ID";
```

My aim is string that part of the string whatever comes after first dot.
So ideally I am expecting output as ***"BO.ID".***

Here is what I have tried:

```
// Checking for the first occurence and take whatever comes after dot
var output = Regex.Match(test, @"^(?=.).*?");
```

The output I am getting is empty.

What is the modification I need to make it for Regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an empty output because the pattern you have can match an empty string at the start of a string, and that is enough since `.*?` is a lazy subpattern and `.` matches any char.

Use (the value will be in `Match.Groups[1].Value`)

```
\.(.*)
```

or (with a lookahead, to get the string as a `Match.Value`)

```
(?<=\.).*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C.(.*)&i=test.BO.ID) and a [C# online demo](http://ideone.com/9vmaoo).

A non-regex approach can be use `String#Split` with `count` argument ([demo](http://ideone.com/wMHyNa)):

```
var s = "test.BO.ID";
var res = s.Split(new[] {"."}, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
if (res.GetLength(0) > 1)
    Console.WriteLine(res[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the part after the first dot you don't need a regex at all:

```
x.Substring(x.IndexOf('.'))
```